# UIStatusBar in iOS7 change color

Tags: ios, ios7, background, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I'm using a `UINavigationController`

for `rootViewController`, I make the navigationBar to transparent

[image]

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The problem is, when I navigate to 2nd viewController

[image]

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Here I set the `navigationBar` color back to green, but the **status bar** doesn't appear in green background.

Is that possible to change the **status bar** background to green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
        addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
        //change this to match your navigation bar or view color or tool bar
        //You can also use addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor]; or any other color
        addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.973.0/255. green:0.973.0/255. blue:0.973.0/255. alpha:1];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and write following code where you set background color of status bar. first create object of appdelegate and call using that.

```
appdelegate.addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:85.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

[Refer this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728970/ios-7-status-bar-background)

Answer (score 3):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];
```

Try this     [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) also